# ExtJS Desktop Issue on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, desktop-application, extjs4.2

I create an application on the skeleton of Extjs Desktop, that save the layout and the position of the window opened in the Desktop. I test and develop all functionality with Chrome, FF, and IE but when i test the loading of the layout of the window i found a bug and i don't know how to resolve it. I realize that this kind of problem is easy to reproduce with all kind of version of IE, in this way: drop a window over the 'StartBar' the page scrolldown so as to show the window completely shifted, like in the image below:

[image]
I use all version of ExtJS > 4.1 
Anyone know any workaround to prevent this kind of behavior that appears only in IE?

Any kind of help is usefull.
Thanks

Comment: try adding `constrain:true` to window config. Refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-constrain)

Comment: @MMT thanks to reply but i try to use `constraint:true`  but nothing change. I try also to use a combination of `constraint:true, renderTo: dataview.id` and the layout issues are more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ask to sencha support i realize that this is not a sencha bug but a different implementation of Browser layout. To resolve this kind of behavior, when in the desktop CreateWindow function i add this property:

`constrain: Ext.isIE,
 constrainHeader: !Ext.isIE,`

This make my application different cross browser but is the only way for resolve that problem. 
I hope is helpful for someone.